# WP7 color picker

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Is there any color picker control for windows phone 7?

I know ColorPicker from [Silverlight Contrib](http://silverlightcontrib.codeplex.com/), but is it usable or have some sort of downside to use it on WP7?

regards,
Stefano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any color picker controls for WP7. The control from the Silverlight Contrib project should work if you compile the source code into a WP7 project. However, you need to take into consideration the touch-based user experience and that the recommended minimum touch point surface is 7mm square. Perhaps a `ListPicker` or `LongListSelector` based approach with pre-defined colors would be more suitable.

Comment: Yes you are right! I didn't consider gestures! Color picking from Contrib is pixel by pixel, not usable at all on the phone! Thanks

Comment: For a wider color choice a simple slider could work too, of course limiting color space only to one dimension limiting Saturation and Luminance for example and letting the user to choose between all Hue possible values.

Answer (score 0):

Check out application of List Picker for this purpose as outlined by David Anson here.

[ListPicker? I hardly even know 'er! [A detailed overview of the Windows Phone Toolkit's ListPicker control] - Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/11/03/listpicker-i-hardly-even-know-er-a-detailed-overview-of-the-windows-phone-toolkit-s-listpicker-control.aspx)

I also understand ColorPicker from the Silverlight Contrib is fine for use on WP7 ([refer James Ashley's comments](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/37be9f8f-e2f2-4b5f-9aef-5d97fa592f99)).